# Dynamically replace a character by another one using javascript, without returning the page back to initial state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a html page full of dynamically loaded content, but one of the characters everywhere needs to be replaced by another one. The reason is that I am opening this page from android, and one of the symbols does not render properly there, so I want to replace it by a similar looking one.

If I use a script like:

```
setInterval(function(){
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\x/g, '\y');
}, 100);
```

it reverts the document back to initial state every 100ms, and for example all text in the input fields is lost. How can I replace the characters without reverting the document back to initial state and losing user input?

EDIT: I am using setInterval because the page changes all the time.

Comment: You may want to loop through all the elements and then replace your character at the leaves. Alternatively, check client on server and don't send such characters.

Comment: @nisargjhaveri If we replace the character at leaves then the document will not revert to initial state? The option of not sending the character is not available to us.

Comment: If you can't replace the problematic character in data, replace it in received raw data. This way you won't need an expensive iterating through the document.

Comment: @Teemu the problem is that I can't modify the code of the document itself, I can only add my own script at the bottom. So I think it will not be practical to modify the raw data, but rather I should modify the resultant document.

Comment: @Sunny88 In that case looks like nisargjhaveri's first suggestion will do the job.

Comment: if you can't modify the raw data at source then filter it at client on receive before modifying the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery, I'm not sure if this is that you want but try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var strNew = $('body').html().replace(/\x/g, '\y');
        $('body').html(strNew);
    },100);
});

</script>
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem because it reverts the document back to initial state after execution. And I need setInterval instead of setTimeout because the document changes all the time and I need to keep replacing the character.

Comment: Sorry @Sunny88 but I think that you're wrong. This solution isn't reverts the document to initial state, only replace the character every 100ms in document every time maintaining the current contents. Have you tried it?

Comment: If you wanted to replace the character every 100ms, then u should have used setInterval, not setTimeout.

Comment: Sorry! you're right, I must use setInterval() instead of setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`. Then it will run only once.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\x/g, '\y');
}, 100);
```

Comment: I need to use setInterval because the page changes all the time. Your solution has the same problem as mine, it will revert the document back to initial state after execution.